# Assigning value to object from the onclick function

Tags: javascript, function, object, button

I'm trying to create a function to handle purchase of the upgrades. Targeting particular upgrade will by done by passing object as parameter to the function (up) and value of upgrade (amount).

This is my player object:

```
var player = {
  tech: 0,
  energy: 0,
  upgrades:{
    engi5Perc: 0,
    engi25Perc: 0,
    andro5Perc: 0,
    andro25Perc: 0,
    robot5Perc: 0,
    robot25Perc: 0
  }
}
```

This is my function:

```
function buyUpgrade(techcost, energycost, up, amount){
  if(techcost <= player.tech && energycost <= player.energy){
    player.tech -= techcost;
    player.energy -= energycost;
    up = amount;
    console.log("Done, upgrade purchased");
  }
}
```

My HTML:

```
<button type="button" onclick="buyUpgrade(1, 1, 'player.upgrades.engi5Perc', 0.005 )">Buy 5%</button>
```

There must be some sort of simple error in my function, and I spent good amount of time trying to figure it out. So far with no luck.

Comment: Can you post the error that you get ?

Comment: `'player.upgrades.engi5Perc'` is just a string. It does not access the `player` object.

Comment: You should also consider using event handlers, instead of using the `onclick` attribute.

Comment: Are event handlers more proper way of adding events to HTML elements nowadays ?

Comment: @KoKsMAN Yes registering event handlers is better. It's a cleaner separation of JS and HTML, allows easier deregistration of handlers and of course multiple event handlers on the same object. Also there is the `Content-Security-Policy` HTTP header, that (among others) disallow browsers to execute inlined scripts to make XSS attacks harder. In order to use this feature your own script needs to be completely separated from the HTML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're currently assigning the amount to the string `'player.upgrades.engi5Perc'`. This doesn't work.

But you can use square brackets to address some object's property, whose name you only know at runtime, e.g. `obj[propertyName] = value`.

Here are some more examples to show the difference:

```
var obj = {foo: 'bar'};
var propertyName = 'foo';
// the following two assignments are essentially equal:
obj.foo = 'newBar';
obj[propertyName] = 'newBar';
// while this one is obviously assigning 'newBar' to the wrong property:
obj.propertyName = 'newBar';
// and this is what happens in your function:
'obj.foo' = 'newBar';
```

Try this:

```
function buyUpgrade(techcost, energycost, up, amount){
  if(techcost <= player.tech && energycost <= player.energy){
    player.tech -= techcost;
    player.energy -= energycost;
    player.upgrades[up] = amount;
    console.log("Done, upgrade purchased");
  }
}
```

and invoke that function with just the name of the upgrade:

```
buyUpgrade(1, 1, 'engi5Perc', 0.005 )
```